# Transition from (classical) serialized custom meta field to (gutenberg) rest enabled meta

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, rest-api, block-editor

I have a custom meta box for saving values from two input fields into a single post meta field.

The data is saved serialized in the DB:

```
get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_key', true )
```

will return:

```
a:2:{s:5:"email";s:10:"hello@me.me";s:6:"number";i:15;}
```

Now, with Gutenberg, I want to move that whole custom meta box into a separate sidebar plugin. So in order to do this, first, I had to add the `__back_compat_meta_box` argument when adding the meta box, so it won't appear in `Sidebar -> Settings -> Document` anymore:

```
    add_meta_box(
        'options',
        'Options',
        [ $this, 'renderOptionsBox' ],
        [ 'post', 'page', 'attachement' ], // the meta field is registered for multiple post types 
        'side',
        'high',
        [ '__back_compat_meta_box' => true ]
    );
```

For the meta field (`_custom_key`) to work with the block editor, it has to be registered using the `register_meta` function:

```
register_meta( string $object_type, string $meta_key, array $args, string|array $deprecated = null )
```

My questions are:

1. [updated] How can I register the custom meta field for **all** of the post types in this list `[ 'post', 'page', 'attachement' ]`?
2. How can I still follow the same serialized way of saving the data in a *single* field if the types ($args->type) supported when registering a meta are only  'string', 'boolean', 'integer', and 'number'?

Right now if I just register the `_custom_key` meta using:

```
    register_meta( 'post', '_custom_key', [
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
        'type' => 'string',
        'auth_callback' => function () {
            return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
        }
    ]);
```

I will get a `Notice: Array to string conversion in .../wp-includes/rest-api/fields/class-wp-rest-meta-fields.php` because already saved data from the DB is serialized.

and typing in the console: `wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPost().meta;` will return a string: `{_custom_key: "Array"}`.

Comment: I don't know the answer to 2 (as far as I can tell, `register_meta()` does not support array values), but in regards to 1, `object_type` is not the same as `post_type`. The object type refers to whether it's for a post type, user or term. If you want to register it for specific post types, set `object_type` to `post` and `object_subtype` (in the args array) to the post type.

Comment: `object_subtype` still accepts only a string. Does that mean that I have to register the meta for *each* post I want?

Comment: Seems that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to question 1 that uses [`register_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/). It's also the start of an answer to question 2 by use of the `prepare_callback` option in `show_in_rest` .

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_89033_register_custom_meta' );
function wpse_89033_register_custom_meta() {

    $post_types = [ 
        'post',
        'page',
        'attachment',
    ];

    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {

        register_post_meta( 
            $post_type,
            '_custom_key',
            array(
                'type'              => 'string',
                'single'            => true,
                'auth_callback'     => function() { 
                    return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
                },
                'show_in_rest'      => [
                    'prepare_callback' => function( $value ) {
                        return wp_json_encode( $value );
                    }
                ],
            ) 
        );

    }

}
```

The documentation for `show_in_rest` (see [`register_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/)) says it's a boolean parameter. But it will accept an options array. To see the options, look at the body of [`get_registered_fields`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_meta_fields/get_registered_fields/), in particular the value of `$default_args`. The `prepare_callback` overrides [`prepare_value`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_meta_fields/prepare_value/), the method in `WP_REST_Meta_Fields` that converted your custom meta value from an array to a string. With our callback, that array will instead be encoded as JSON.

On the JavaScript side, here are some key declarations.

```
// Get the custom meta
let customMeta = wp.data.select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta');

// Parse the meta so you can do some JS with it
let parsed = JSON.parse(customMeta._custom_key);

// Do some JS with the parsed meta...

// Stringify the parsed meta before dispatching it
let stringified = JSON.stringify(parsed);

/*
 * Dispatch (update) the meta (and don't forget to
 * save/publish/update the post to ensure the meta goes in the database)
 */ 
wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editPost({meta: {_custom_key: stringified}});
```

Back in PHP land, getting and updating your custom meta will now work differently. When you call `get_post_meta`, you're used to getting an array, and you'll probably still want one sometimes. But if you last updated your custom meta via the WP REST API, you're getting a JSON string. In that case, you'll have to use [`json_decode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/json_decode/). One approach would be to wrap calls to `get_post_meta` like so:

```
function wpse_89033_get_custom_meta( $post_id, $meta_key ) {

    $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );

    // If $post_meta is a string that's not empty
    if ( $post_meta && is_string( $post_meta ) ) {

        /*
         * Use the decoded JSON string or else the original string 
         * if decoding fails, e.g., if the string isn't JSON
         */ 
        $post_meta = json_decode( $post_meta, true ) ?: $post_meta;

    }

    return $post_meta;

}
```

If you make changes to your custom meta as an array, don't worry about re-encoding before calling `update_post_meta`. The `prepare_callback` will handle re-encoding.

About updating in PHP, calling `update_post_meta` during `save_post`, as shown in the [official plugin handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/#saving-values), appears to override updates made via the WP REST API. So one more thing to consider is conditioning any `save_post` update to your custom meta on whether the post is being edited in Gutenberg. If it is, leave the update to the REST API.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks a lot for getting into details -- that saved my day. Cheers.

Comment: Update: I left this solution if favor of a `register_rest_field()` call -- it's much more flexible. If anyone needs it, I can fill a full response describing the approach.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress 5.3 you can now register meta with the `array` and `object` meta type. Here is the post from Make WordPress Core which gives all the details with examples:

- https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/03/wp-5-3-supports-object-and-array-meta-types-in-the-rest-api/